# python excel подсчет дубликатов

Tags: python, excel

Подскажите какую библиотеку лучше использовать при работе с excel из python если нужно из следующей структуры файла получать такие данные

[image: Пример]

Comment: я пользуюсь библиотекой openpyxl, пока что для всех манипуляций с экселем достаточно. Но прошу заметить работает только с .xlsx файлами.

Comment: а как реализовать мое алго с openpyxl ?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)